# Python C API importing a module with PyRun_String

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I am trying to use

```
PyRun_String(string, Py_eval_input, dict1, dict2);
```

to import a module, but I am getting a syntax error. Is there a way to import built-in or third-party modules with PyRun_String?

Comment: Can you post more information (see MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `Py_eval_input` indicates a single *expression*. `import` is a statement but is not part of an expression

Comment: Re *"getting a syntax error"*: What is the error message?